# return json to ajax in symfony?

Tags: symfony1

In symfony, I call an action and I want this to return json to jQuery frontend.

The Jobeet tutorial teaches how to return a partial but I want to return json, not a partial.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If it's just a normal AJAX action you're returning it from, I think I've used the following somewhere in the past:

```
return $this->renderText(json_encode($something));
```

Comment: If you have the web debugging bar active in dev mode, you must add the line "sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug',false);"

Comment: This will return json in the response body, but the content type will be text/html. Add `$this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/json');`

Answer (score 17):

**The cheap way:**

```
function executeSomethingThatReturnsJson(){
  $M = new Model();
  $stuff = $M->getStuff();
  echo json_encode($stuff);
  die(); //don't do any view stuff
}
```

**The smarter way:**

A smarter way is to create a nice subclass of sfActions that helps handling json-stuff.

In a project I did recently, I created a application called 'api' (`./symfony generate:application api`)

and then created a file like:

api/lib/apiActions.class.php

```
<?PHP
class apiActions extends sfActions {
  public function returnJson($data){
    $this->data = $data;
    if (sfConfig::get('sf_environment') == 'dev' && !$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()){
      $this->setLayout('json_debug'); 
      $this->setTemplate('json_debug','main');
    }else{
      $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type','application/json');
      $this->setLayout('json');
      $this->setTemplate('json','main');
    }
  } 
}
```

Notice that I explicitly set the template there.

So my jsonSuccess.php template is simply:

```
<?PHP echo json_encode($data);
```

While json_debugSuccess.php makes things prettier:

```
<?PHP var_dump($data); ?>
```

Then you can have a controller that extends apiActions (instead of the usual sfActions) that looks like this:

```
<?php
class myActions extends apiAction {
  public function executeList(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $params = array();
    if ($request->hasParameter('id')){
      $id = $request->getParameter('id');
      if (is_numeric($id)){
        $params['id'] = $id;
      }
    }
    $data = Doctrine::getTable('SomeTable')->findAll();
    $this->returnJson($data);
  }
}
```

Disclaimer:  The code above is copy/pasted out of an app I have, but simplified.  It's for illustrative purposes only -- but it should get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: this was really funny :) u posted a lot of codes but the previous answer was one line and it worked :) 1+ for u being eager to help though!:)

Comment: Right -- that other answer is a nicer version of "the cheap way".  The rest of my answer is about handling things differently based on environment, though I'm sure it could be done a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

FYI: In case of Symfony 2.x "quick and dirty" way looks like this:

```
return  new Response(json_encode($data), 200, array('Content-Type', 'text/json'));
```

Comment: I think you can even just put `Response(json_encode($data))` if your route specifies the good format (`defaults: { _controller: your:action, _format: json }`)

Answer (score 0):

Return new JsonResponse(array);